# Create Android application directory compatible with all versions and devices

Tags: android, directory, android-external-storage, android-storage

I need an Android application directory path to my application pictures compatilbe with all versions. I have searched a lot and I hadn't find anything compatible with ALL devices yet. Now we have this piece of code but it is still giving NullPointerExcepction at `picturesDir.exists()` with `U55` and `ZTE` devices.

```
    File picturesDir;
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    // Make sure it's available, if there is no SD card, create new directory objects to make
    // directory on device.
    if (!Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
        picturesDir = new File(Environment.getDataDirectory() + "/data/" + getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + "/Pictures/");
    } else if (Environment.getExternalStorageState() != null) {
        picturesDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    } else{
        String externalStoragePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .getAbsolutePath();
        picturesDir = new File(externalStoragePath + getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + "/Pictures/");
    }

    if (!picturesDir.exists()) {
        picturesDir.mkdir();
    }
```

[image]

What should we do? I don't want to check if it is null to avoid the crash. I want a path where I can save pictures. Thanks.

Comment: "it is still giving NullPointerExcepction" -- please edit your question and post the complete Java stack trace associated with this exception. I believe that your algorithm, as much as the device, is the source of your difficulty, and the stack trace will help me confirm your symptoms.

Comment: Even if you somehow avoid error during checking for SD card state, it is possible that SD card is extracted anytime or an IO error happens. So you have to catch IO errors anyway. Don't try to make that code pretty at all costs, you can not do that.

Comment: Just edited CommonsWare!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per documentation of getExternalFilesDir: "the absolute path to application-specific directory. May return null if shared storage is not currently available". So according to documentation, you *have* to check for null, if you use `getExternalFilesDir`.

There may be other reasons why external storage is not available besides not being mounted. There is also a possibility of race between calling `getExternalStorageState` and calling `getExternalFilesDir`. In other words, the SD card may be unmounted immediately after call to getExternalStorageState() reports it as mounted, but before call to getExternalFilesDir. This race condition may result in your crash.

Comment: Thank you! I'll check on that and if some users still give that error I'll come back here. Thanks.